# Why when I create one field in sale.py it is not created in Postgresql database?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

I have a problem because when I create a field in sale.order.line model. This field does not appear in the database Postgresql when I make a query in sale_order_line.

This is the statement I created field in the model sale.order.line :

```
niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", default=" ", readonly=True)
```

Please if anyone could help me , I'll be very grateful. Thank you for your time and dedication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a computed field. If you need to be stored you need to add, as parameter:

```
store=True
```

Comment: Thanks, but now Odoo shows me the following error:

ProgrammingError: column "niu" of relation "sale_order_line" does not exist
LINE 1: ...roduct_id", "product_packaging", "qty_delivered", "niu", "cr...

Comment: Did you restart the server? You should also upgrade the module.